# Garbage collection in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks, marionette, garbage

*** Updated - Added a sample code for one of the view ***

This has been discussed a number of times and I have gone through a lot of suggestion on this topic but I still don't have any luck.

My application is tab based i.e. user searches for an entity in a global search box and on selection of the entity the view/model is generated and view is rendered under a new tab.User can open multiple tabs by repeating the above process.

The problem I am facing is every time a new tab is opened I can see the browser memory consumption goes up by approx 6 MB (the data fetched & displayed for each tab is max 60kb).

Not only that but when I close a tab I can see my custom close function (copied below) being called for each view under that tab but somehow the browser memory does not go down. This to me means the garbage collection is not working or the view/models have not been cleaned up properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
define([
    "hbs!modules/applications/templates/applications",
    "vent"
],
function (tpl, vent) {

    var View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        className: 'modApplications',

        template: {
            type: 'handlebars',
            template: tpl
        },

        refresh: function(){
            self.$('.body-of-table').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            self.$('.application-panel .spinnerDiv').addClass('loading');
            this.model.fetch().always(function(){
                self.$('.application-panel .spinnerDiv').removeClass('loading');
            });
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
            vent.bindTo(vent, 'updateApplications', this.refresh, this);
        },

        onShow: function(){
            var self = this;
            this.$el.on('click', '.action-refresh', function(e) {
                self.refresh();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        },

        close: function() {
            _.each(this.bindings, function (binding) {
                binding.model.unbind(binding.ev, binding.callback);
            });
            this.bindings = [];
            this.unbind();
            this.off();
            this.model.off('change');
            this.model.unbind('change', this.render, this);
            this.remove();
            delete this.$el;
            delete this.el;
            if(console) console.log("kill : view.applications");
        }

    });

    return View;

});
```

Comment: I'm afraid this will not be enough code you have showed us. Memory leakage in JavaScript is most likely due to uncleaned object references; especially cross references between DOM nodes and JS objects are dirty. Check your code for any references to sub-objects and methods. Also make sure DOM elements do not, for example through event handlers, reference anonymous functions aka closures.

Comment: I have updated the post and added a typical view structure I use. Can you please have a look and see if I have missed any cleaning within the View.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't worked a lot with backbone.js. I can't tell how it deals with event bindings. For example, I don't know how relevant it is to unbind `vent.bindTo(vent, 'updateApplications', this.refresh, this);` or if it is enough to simply delete the reference to `this.$el` to which you've bound a click event. Also you might have missed cleaning out `View` after it was returned. Like I said, zones with greatest potential to leak memory include object references and especially cross references between DOM and JS like event handlers. Though the API should take care of those for you...

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem & the fix.

The issue was that I was using ONE global Marionette.EventAggregator for all new tabs. This was used as a means to communication between various sections within a tab. Now, when a tab is closed the main.js file still held reference to the global vent as other tabs are still using it. This is where a reference to the closed tab was still held and hence the views/models were not gc'ed.

To fix this I created a separate vent for each tab and used that vent object to trigger any event within that tab. On tab close action I unbindAll events and assign a null reference to the vent for tab which is to be closed.

Hope this helps someone in future.